# Irregularly spaced heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to create a heatmap based on the matrix and bounds below and then plot the data (x1, x2) to see dots falling into the respective classes.
The best I could do was use seaborn, but since the classes on both axes are not evenly spaced, it's hard to read the values corresponding to a dot, on both axes.
Is there a way (using seaborn or any other library) to have the cell sizes of the heatmap proportional to the numbers of bounds1, bounds2, so that the values on the axis respect the right proportions?
Below my example code.
Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

bounds1 = [  0. , 3. , 27.25 , 51.5  , 75.75 , 100.  ]
bounds2 = [   0. , 127.,  165.,  334. , 522. , 837., 1036., 1316., 1396., 3000]
matrix = [[0.3    , 0.5    , 0.7    , 0.9    , 1.    ,  0.9    , 0.7    , 0.4  ,   0.3    , 0.3    ],
          [0.22725, 0.37875, 0.53025, 0.68175, 0.7575,  0.68175, 0.53025, 0.303,   0.22725, 0.22725],
          [0.1545 , 0.2575 , 0.3605 , 0.4635 , 0.515 ,  0.4635 , 0.3605 , 0.206,   0.1545 , 0.1545 ],
          [0.08175, 0.13625, 0.19075, 0.24525, 0.2725,  0.24525, 0.19075, 0.109,   0.08175, 0.08175],
          [0.009  , 0.015  , 0.021  , 0.027  , 0.03  ,  0.027  , 0.021  , 0.012,   0.009  , 0.009  ],
          [0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.    ,  0.     , 0.     , 0.   ,   0.     , 0.     ]]
x2 = np.array([1.7765000e+00, 3.9435000e+00, 4.5005002e+00, 4.5005002e+00,
       5.0325003e+00, 6.0124998e+00, 7.0035005e+00, 8.5289993e+00,
       1.0150000e+01, 1.1111500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.2193500e+01,
       1.2193500e+01, 1.3665500e+01, 1.4780001e+01, 1.5908000e+01,
       1.7007000e+01, 1.8597000e+01, 2.0439001e+01, 2.2047001e+01,
       2.4724501e+01, 2.7719501e+01, 3.0307501e+01, 3.3042500e+01,
       3.6326000e+01, 3.8622997e+01, 4.1292500e+01, 4.4293495e+01,
       4.7881500e+01, 5.1105499e+01, 5.3708996e+01, 5.6908497e+01,
       5.9103497e+01, 6.1926003e+01, 6.6175499e+01, 6.9841499e+01,
       7.3534996e+01, 7.8712997e+01, 8.3992500e+01, 8.7227493e+01,
       9.1489487e+01, 9.6500992e+01, 1.0068549e+02, 1.0625399e+02,
       1.1245149e+02, 1.1828050e+02, 1.2343950e+02, 1.2875299e+02,
       1.3531699e+02, 1.4146500e+02, 1.4726399e+02, 1.5307101e+02,
       1.5917000e+02, 1.6554350e+02, 1.7167050e+02, 1.7897350e+02,
       1.8766650e+02, 1.9705751e+02, 2.0610300e+02, 2.1421350e+02,
       2.2146150e+02, 2.2975949e+02, 2.3886848e+02, 2.4766153e+02,
       2.5618802e+02, 2.6506250e+02, 2.7528250e+02, 2.8465201e+02,
       2.9246451e+02, 3.0088300e+02, 3.1069800e+02, 3.2031000e+02,
       3.2950650e+02, 3.3929001e+02, 3.4919598e+02, 3.5904755e+02,
       3.6873303e+02, 3.7849451e+02, 3.8831549e+02, 3.9915201e+02,
       4.1044501e+02, 4.2201651e+02, 4.3467300e+02, 4.4735904e+02,
       4.5926651e+02, 4.7117001e+02, 4.8231406e+02, 4.9426105e+02,
       5.0784149e+02, 5.2100049e+02, 5.3492249e+02, 5.4818701e+02,
       5.6144202e+02, 5.7350153e+02, 5.8634998e+02, 5.9905096e+02,
       6.1240802e+02, 6.2555353e+02, 6.3893542e+02, 6.5263202e+02,
       6.6708154e+02, 6.8029950e+02, 6.9236456e+02, 7.0441150e+02,
       7.1579163e+02, 7.2795203e+02, 7.4106995e+02, 7.5507953e+02,
       7.6881946e+02, 7.8363702e+02, 7.9864905e+02, 8.1473901e+02,
       8.3018762e+02, 8.4492249e+02, 8.6007306e+02, 8.7455353e+02,
       8.8938556e+02, 9.0509601e+02, 9.2196307e+02, 9.3774091e+02,
       9.5391345e+02, 9.7015198e+02, 9.8671466e+02, 1.0042726e+03,
       1.0209606e+03, 1.0379355e+03, 1.0547625e+03, 1.0726985e+03,
       1.0912705e+03, 1.1100559e+03, 1.1288949e+03, 1.1476450e+03,
       1.1654260e+03, 1.1823262e+03, 1.1997356e+03, 1.2171041e+03,
       1.2353951e+03, 1.2535184e+03, 1.2718250e+03, 1.2903676e+03,
       1.3086545e+03, 1.3270005e+03, 1.3444775e+03, 1.3612805e+03,
       1.3784171e+03, 1.3958615e+03, 1.4131825e+03, 1.4311034e+03,
       1.4489685e+03, 1.4677334e+03, 1.4869026e+03, 1.5062087e+03,
       1.5258719e+03, 1.5452015e+03, 1.5653271e+03, 1.5853635e+03,
       1.6053860e+03, 1.6247255e+03, 1.6436824e+03, 1.6632330e+03,
       1.6819221e+03, 1.7011276e+03, 1.7198782e+03, 1.7383060e+03,
       1.7565670e+03, 1.7749023e+03, 1.7950280e+03, 1.8149988e+03,
       1.8360586e+03, 1.8572985e+03, 1.8782219e+03, 1.8991390e+03,
       1.9200371e+03, 1.9395586e+03, 1.9595035e+03, 1.9790668e+03,
       1.9995455e+03, 2.0203715e+03, 2.0416791e+03, 2.0616587e+03,
       2.0819294e+03, 2.1032202e+03, 2.1253989e+03, 2.1470112e+03,
       2.1686660e+03, 2.1908926e+03, 2.2129436e+03, 2.2349995e+03,
       2.2567026e+03, 2.2784224e+03, 2.2997925e+03, 2.3198750e+03,
       2.3393770e+03, 2.3588149e+03, 2.3783970e+03, 2.3988135e+03,
       2.4175618e+03, 2.4363840e+03, 2.4572385e+03, 2.4773455e+03,
       2.4965142e+03, 2.5157107e+03, 2.5354666e+03, 2.5554331e+03,
       2.5757551e+03, 2.5955181e+03, 2.6157085e+03, 2.6348906e+03,
       2.6535190e+03, 2.6727512e+03, 2.6923147e+03, 2.7118843e+03])
x1 = np.array([28.427988  , 28.891748  , 30.134018  , 29.833858  , 30.540195  ,
       31.762226  , 32.163025  , 31.623648  , 31.964993  , 32.73733   ,
       32.562325  , 32.89953   , 33.064743  , 32.76882   , 32.1024    ,
       32.171394  , 33.363426  , 34.328148  , 36.24527   , 35.877434  ,
       35.29762   , 35.193832  , 35.61119   , 36.50994   , 35.615444  ,
       35.2758    , 34.447975  , 34.183205  , 35.781815  , 35.510662  ,
       35.277668  , 35.26543   , 34.944313  , 35.301414  , 34.63578   ,
       34.36223   , 35.496872  , 35.488243  , 35.494583  , 35.21087   ,
       34.275524  , 33.945126  , 33.63986   , 33.904293  , 33.553017  ,
       34.348408  , 33.84105   , 32.8437    , 32.19287   , 31.688663  ,
       32.035015  , 31.641226  , 31.138266  , 30.629492  , 30.111526  ,
       29.571909  , 29.244211  , 28.42031   , 27.908197  , 27.316568  ,
       26.909412  , 25.928982  , 25.03047   , 24.354822  , 23.54626   ,
       22.88031   , 23.000391  , 22.300774  , 21.988918  , 21.467094  ,
       21.730871  , 23.060678  , 22.910374  , 24.45383   , 23.610855  ,
       24.594006  , 24.263508  , 25.077124  , 23.9773    , 22.611958  ,
       21.88306   , 21.014484  , 19.674965  , 18.745205  , 20.225956  ,
       19.433172  , 19.451014  , 18.264421  , 17.588757  , 16.837574  ,
       17.252535  , 18.967127  , 19.111462  , 19.90994   , 19.15653   ,
       18.49522   , 17.376019  , 17.35794   , 16.200405  , 17.9445    ,
       18.545986  , 17.69698   , 20.665318  , 20.90071   , 20.32658   ,
       21.27805   , 21.145922  , 19.32898   , 19.160307  , 18.60541   ,
       18.902897  , 18.843922  , 17.890692  , 18.197395  , 17.662706  ,
       18.578962  , 18.898802  , 18.435923  , 17.644451  , 16.393314  ,
       15.570944  , 16.779602  , 15.74104   , 15.041967  , 14.544464  ,
       15.014386  , 14.156769  , 13.591232  , 12.386208  , 11.133551  ,
       10.472783  ,  9.7923355 , 10.571391  , 11.245247  , 10.063455  ,
       10.742685  ,  8.819294  ,  8.141182  ,  6.9487176 ,  6.3410373 ,
        7.033326  ,  6.5856943 ,  6.0214376 ,  6.6087174 ,  9.583405  ,
        9.4608135 ,  9.183213  , 10.673293  ,  9.477165  ,  8.667246  ,
        7.3392615 ,  6.2609572 ,  5.5752296 ,  4.4312773 ,  4.0997415 ,
        4.127005  ,  4.072541  ,  3.5704772 ,  2.7370691 ,  2.3750854 ,
        2.0708292 ,  3.4086852 ,  3.8237891 ,  3.9072614 ,  3.1760776 ,
        2.4963813 ,  1.5232614 ,  0.931248  ,  0.49159998,  0.21676798,
        0.874704  ,  2.0560641 ,  1.5494559 ,  3.0944476 ,  2.6151357 ,
        2.7285278 ,  3.4450078 ,  3.4614875 ,  5.779072  ,  8.063728  ,
        7.7077436 ,  7.8576636 ,  7.4494233 ,  6.5933595 ,  6.1667037 ,
        4.9452477 ,  5.6894236 ,  6.0578876 ,  5.9922714 ,  5.060448  ,
        6.074832  ,  6.7870073 ,  5.7388477 ,  5.8681116 ,  4.7604475 ,
        4.2740316 ,  3.785328  ,  4.060576  ,  4.9203672 ,  5.355184  ,
        4.793792  ,  3.8007674 ,  3.6115997 ,  2.7794237 ,  2.5385118 ,
        5.1410074 ,  5.5506234 ,  7.638063  ,  7.512544  ,  6.617264  ,
        6.5637918 ,  6.452815  ])

# define colormap
N=5 # number of desired color bins
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn_r  
cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
cmap = cmap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N)

# define the bins and normalize 
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1) 
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(matrix, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, ax=ax, linewidths=0.1)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major')
ax.set_xticklabels(bounds2)
ax.set_yticklabels(bounds1)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks(bounds)
cbar.set_ticklabels(bounds)

x2_idx = np.interp(x2, bounds2, range(len(bounds2)))+0.5 # +0.5: to shift data start to bin center
x1_idx = np.interp(x1, bounds1, range(len(bounds1)))+0.5 # +0.5: to shift data start to bin center
ax.plot(x2_idx,  x1_idx, color='black', marker='o')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pcolormesh` can be handy here. It allows assigning colors to an unevenly-spaced grid. Note that the 6 boundaries in `bounds1` delimit 5 rows, so the last row of `matrix` will be ignored. Similarly, the 10 boundaries in `bounds2` delimit 9 columns, ignoring the last one. You might want to add an extra boundary at the start or end if you need all cells.

The x-ticks can be rotated to avoid overlapping.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

bounds1 = [  0. , 3. , 27.25 , 51.5  , 75.75 , 100.  ]
bounds2 = [   0. , 127.,  165.,  334. , 522. , 837., 1036., 1316., 1396., 3000]
matrix = [[0.3    , 0.5    , 0.7    , 0.9    , 1.    ,  0.9    , 0.7    , 0.4  ,   0.3    , 0.3    ],
          [0.22725, 0.37875, 0.53025, 0.68175, 0.7575,  0.68175, 0.53025, 0.303,   0.22725, 0.22725],
          [0.1545 , 0.2575 , 0.3605 , 0.4635 , 0.515 ,  0.4635 , 0.3605 , 0.206,   0.1545 , 0.1545 ],
          [0.08175, 0.13625, 0.19075, 0.24525, 0.2725,  0.24525, 0.19075, 0.109,   0.08175, 0.08175],
          [0.009  , 0.015  , 0.021  , 0.027  , 0.03  ,  0.027  , 0.021  , 0.012,   0.009  , 0.009  ],
          [0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.     , 0.    ,  0.     , 0.     , 0.   ,   0.     , 0.     ]]
x2 = np.array([1.7765000e+00, 3.9435000e+00, 4.5005002e+00, 4.5005002e+00, 5.0325003e+00, 6.0124998e+00, 7.0035005e+00, 8.5289993e+00, 1.0150000e+01, 1.1111500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.2193500e+01, 1.3665500e+01, 1.4780001e+01, 1.5908000e+01, 1.7007000e+01, 1.8597000e+01, 2.0439001e+01, 2.2047001e+01, 2.4724501e+01, 2.7719501e+01, 3.0307501e+01, 3.3042500e+01, 3.6326000e+01, 3.8622997e+01, 4.1292500e+01, 4.4293495e+01, 4.7881500e+01, 5.1105499e+01, 5.3708996e+01, 5.6908497e+01, 5.9103497e+01, 6.1926003e+01, 6.6175499e+01, 6.9841499e+01, 7.3534996e+01, 7.8712997e+01, 8.3992500e+01, 8.7227493e+01, 9.1489487e+01, 9.6500992e+01, 1.0068549e+02, 1.0625399e+02, 1.1245149e+02, 1.1828050e+02, 1.2343950e+02, 1.2875299e+02, 1.3531699e+02, 1.4146500e+02, 1.4726399e+02, 1.5307101e+02, 1.5917000e+02, 1.6554350e+02, 1.7167050e+02, 1.7897350e+02, 1.8766650e+02, 1.9705751e+02, 2.0610300e+02, 2.1421350e+02, 2.2146150e+02, 2.2975949e+02, 2.3886848e+02, 2.4766153e+02, 2.5618802e+02, 2.6506250e+02, 2.7528250e+02, 2.8465201e+02, 2.9246451e+02, 3.0088300e+02, 3.1069800e+02, 3.2031000e+02, 3.2950650e+02, 3.3929001e+02, 3.4919598e+02, 3.5904755e+02, 3.6873303e+02, 3.7849451e+02, 3.8831549e+02, 3.9915201e+02, 4.1044501e+02, 4.2201651e+02, 4.3467300e+02, 4.4735904e+02, 4.5926651e+02, 4.7117001e+02, 4.8231406e+02, 4.9426105e+02, 5.0784149e+02, 5.2100049e+02, 5.3492249e+02, 5.4818701e+02, 5.6144202e+02, 5.7350153e+02, 5.8634998e+02, 5.9905096e+02, 6.1240802e+02, 6.2555353e+02, 6.3893542e+02, 6.5263202e+02, 6.6708154e+02, 6.8029950e+02, 6.9236456e+02, 7.0441150e+02, 7.1579163e+02, 7.2795203e+02, 7.4106995e+02, 7.5507953e+02, 7.6881946e+02, 7.8363702e+02, 7.9864905e+02, 8.1473901e+02, 8.3018762e+02, 8.4492249e+02, 8.6007306e+02, 8.7455353e+02, 8.8938556e+02, 9.0509601e+02, 9.2196307e+02, 9.3774091e+02, 9.5391345e+02, 9.7015198e+02, 9.8671466e+02, 1.0042726e+03, 1.0209606e+03, 1.0379355e+03, 1.0547625e+03, 1.0726985e+03, 1.0912705e+03, 1.1100559e+03, 1.1288949e+03, 1.1476450e+03, 1.1654260e+03, 1.1823262e+03, 1.1997356e+03, 1.2171041e+03, 1.2353951e+03, 1.2535184e+03, 1.2718250e+03, 1.2903676e+03, 1.3086545e+03, 1.3270005e+03, 1.3444775e+03, 1.3612805e+03, 1.3784171e+03, 1.3958615e+03, 1.4131825e+03, 1.4311034e+03, 1.4489685e+03, 1.4677334e+03, 1.4869026e+03, 1.5062087e+03, 1.5258719e+03, 1.5452015e+03, 1.5653271e+03, 1.5853635e+03, 1.6053860e+03, 1.6247255e+03, 1.6436824e+03, 1.6632330e+03, 1.6819221e+03, 1.7011276e+03, 1.7198782e+03, 1.7383060e+03, 1.7565670e+03, 1.7749023e+03, 1.7950280e+03, 1.8149988e+03, 1.8360586e+03, 1.8572985e+03, 1.8782219e+03, 1.8991390e+03, 1.9200371e+03, 1.9395586e+03, 1.9595035e+03, 1.9790668e+03, 1.9995455e+03, 2.0203715e+03, 2.0416791e+03, 2.0616587e+03, 2.0819294e+03, 2.1032202e+03, 2.1253989e+03, 2.1470112e+03, 2.1686660e+03, 2.1908926e+03, 2.2129436e+03, 2.2349995e+03, 2.2567026e+03, 2.2784224e+03, 2.2997925e+03, 2.3198750e+03, 2.3393770e+03, 2.3588149e+03, 2.3783970e+03, 2.3988135e+03, 2.4175618e+03, 2.4363840e+03, 2.4572385e+03, 2.4773455e+03, 2.4965142e+03, 2.5157107e+03, 2.5354666e+03, 2.5554331e+03, 2.5757551e+03, 2.5955181e+03, 2.6157085e+03, 2.6348906e+03, 2.6535190e+03, 2.6727512e+03, 2.6923147e+03, 2.7118843e+03])
x1 = np.array([28.427988, 28.891748, 30.134018, 29.833858, 30.540195, 31.762226, 32.163025, 31.623648, 31.964993, 32.73733, 32.562325, 32.89953, 33.064743, 32.76882, 32.1024, 32.171394, 33.363426, 34.328148, 36.24527, 35.877434, 35.29762, 35.193832, 35.61119, 36.50994, 35.615444, 35.2758, 34.447975, 34.183205, 35.781815, 35.510662, 35.277668, 35.26543, 34.944313, 35.301414, 34.63578, 34.36223, 35.496872, 35.488243, 35.494583, 35.21087, 34.275524, 33.945126, 33.63986, 33.904293, 33.553017, 34.348408, 33.84105, 32.8437, 32.19287, 31.688663, 32.035015, 31.641226, 31.138266, 30.629492, 30.111526, 29.571909, 29.244211, 28.42031, 27.908197, 27.316568, 26.909412, 25.928982, 25.03047, 24.354822, 23.54626, 22.88031, 23.000391, 22.300774, 21.988918, 21.467094, 21.730871, 23.060678, 22.910374, 24.45383, 23.610855, 24.594006, 24.263508, 25.077124, 23.9773, 22.611958, 21.88306, 21.014484, 19.674965, 18.745205, 20.225956, 19.433172, 19.451014, 18.264421, 17.588757, 16.837574, 17.252535, 18.967127, 19.111462, 19.90994, 19.15653, 18.49522, 17.376019, 17.35794, 16.200405, 17.9445, 18.545986, 17.69698, 20.665318, 20.90071, 20.32658, 21.27805, 21.145922, 19.32898, 19.160307, 18.60541, 18.902897, 18.843922, 17.890692, 18.197395, 17.662706, 18.578962, 18.898802, 18.435923, 17.644451, 16.393314, 15.570944, 16.779602, 15.74104, 15.041967, 14.544464, 15.014386, 14.156769, 13.591232, 12.386208, 11.133551, 10.472783, 9.7923355, 10.571391, 11.245247, 10.063455, 10.742685, 8.819294, 8.141182, 6.9487176, 6.3410373, 7.033326, 6.5856943, 6.0214376, 6.6087174, 9.583405, 9.4608135, 9.183213, 10.673293, 9.477165, 8.667246, 7.3392615, 6.2609572, 5.5752296, 4.4312773, 4.0997415, 4.127005, 4.072541, 3.5704772, 2.7370691, 2.3750854, 2.0708292, 3.4086852, 3.8237891, 3.9072614, 3.1760776, 2.4963813, 1.5232614, 0.931248, 0.49159998, 0.21676798, 0.874704, 2.0560641, 1.5494559, 3.0944476, 2.6151357, 2.7285278, 3.4450078, 3.4614875, 5.779072, 8.063728, 7.7077436, 7.8576636, 7.4494233, 6.5933595, 6.1667037, 4.9452477, 5.6894236, 6.0578876, 5.9922714, 5.060448, 6.074832, 6.7870073, 5.7388477, 5.8681116, 4.7604475, 4.2740316, 3.785328, 4.060576, 4.9203672, 5.355184, 4.793792, 3.8007674, 3.6115997, 2.7794237, 2.5385118, 5.1410074, 5.5506234, 7.638063, 7.512544, 6.617264, 6.5637918, 6.452815])

# define colormap
N = 5  # number of desired color bins
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlGn_r', N)

# define the bins and normalize
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, N + 1)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
colormesh = ax.pcolormesh(bounds2, bounds1, matrix, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, linewidths=0.1)
# ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', rotation=50)
ax.set_xticks(bounds2)
ax.set_yticks(bounds1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(colormesh, ax=ax)
cbar.set_ticks(bounds)
ax.plot(x2, x1, color='black', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]